# Escaping Angle Brackets in XML in Eclipse / Android

Tags: android, xml

If I want to to label some buttons with ">" and "<" symbols, what's the correct way to escape them out in the XML file?   The presence of either ">" or "&" (as in "&gt") produces "invalid token" errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is `&gt;` (ie with semi-colons)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I get a list of the XML document escape characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Either specify those characters like this:

```
< = &lt;
> = &gt;
```

Or use a CDATA section and put those characters inside:

```
<![CDATA[<]]>
<![CDATA[>]]>
```

Comment: it was the semicolons...  8-(

Comment: I am using &lt; in my XML. It works fine the first time, and then the SDK encodes that for some reason, so it turns to %amp;gt;. Any idea?