# Malformed Android Manifest

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

Can someone tell me why my AndroidManifest.xml is malformed?
I am getting this error when trying to run the app on my device : 
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.au.testapp"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.002" >

    <!-- USES PERMISSIONS -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.au.testapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

    <!-- PERMISSIONS -->
    <permission android:name="com.au.testapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <permission android:name="com.au.testapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- SDK VERISONS -->
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <!-- USES FEATURES -->
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />

    <!-- SCREEN SUPPORT -->
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/TitleBarTheme"
        android:name=".AnalyticsApplication">

        <!-- ACTIVITIES -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.au.testapp.SplashScreen"
            android:configChanges="navigation|screenLayout|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.au.testapp.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="navigation|screenLayout|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection|keyboard"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.au.testapp.VideoCaptureActivity"
            android:configChanges="navigation|screenLayout|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.au.testapp.PhotoCaptureActivity"
            android:configChanges="navigation|screenLayout|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.au.testapp.VerifyActivity"
            android:configChanges="navigation|screenLayout|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection|keyboard"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.au.testapp.dialog.DialogMapTypeActivity"
            android:configChanges="navigation|screenLayout|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection|keyboard"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.au.testapp.dialog.DialogRadarTimesActivity"
            android:configChanges="navigation|screenLayout|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection|keyboard"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.crittercism.NotificationActivity" />

        <!-- USES LIBRARIES -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <!-- SERVICES -->
        <service android:name="com.au.testapp.BackgroundLocationService"   />
        <service android:name="com.au.testapp.GCMIntentService" />
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" /> 

        <!-- RECEIVERS -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.au.testapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- META DATA -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Gradle File :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://jzaccone.github.io/SlidingMenu-aar" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu:library:1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

I left out the Maps meta-data value for privacy

Comment: perhaps you should should decompile the APK and check the manifest and compare it to your local one and check if there is a difference.

Comment: I've compared the old one with the new, it looks the same, problem is i've moved to Android studio so i'm not sure if my Gradle file has something to do with it

Comment: Look for W/PackageParser in the logcat when installing your apk to find whats causing the error.

Comment: Searched my LogCat, can't find any text relating to PackageParser ;(

Comment: try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25329580/3467204

Comment: Nah that didn't work @WannaBeGeek

Comment: check this answer if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/25646008/2686502

Comment: Thanks @jayeshsolanki93 , ended up finding the W/PackageManager.  For some reason when you search for it in LogCat it doesn't find it, but it is there!  W/PackageManager: Failed parse during installPackageLI
                                                            android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: /data/app/vmdl1759615828.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #159): <meta-data> requires an android:value or android:resource attribute

Comment: @Nickmccomb I am glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try one thing 
remove the category from your manifest file and then try to install

```
 <category android:name="com.au.testapp" />

       <Intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"                 />
            <category android:name="com.au.testapp" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: didn't work :( still have the same error: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]