# "URI is not registered" error Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

My app compiles successfully, but I get this error:

```
URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Fragmeworks | Schemas and DTDs)
```

at

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
```

in my arabic strings.xml

---

I've seen these links:

1. [Why is Android Studio reporting "URI is not registered"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883427/why-is-android-studio-reporting-uri-is-not-registered)
2. [Android Studio: Error parsing XML & URI is not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511254/android-studio-error-parsing-xml-uri-is-not-registered?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. [Why am I getting error message "URI is not Registered"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569610/why-am-i-getting-error-message-uri-is-not-registered?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But none of them helped me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out I was editing the DEBUG version of the strings.xml, to fix it, simply close the tab that has the error and re-open it.